# ffmpeg: significant lag and poor audio sync when combining audio and video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to combining audio and video for streaming from a Raspberry Pi. The audio leads the video by a few seconds, whether I stream the output or write it to a file.

Command line:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 | ffmpeg -report -probesize 32000 -thread_queue_size 1024 -y -f h264 -r 25 -framerate 25 -i - -thread_queue_size 512 -f alsa -ac 1 -channel_layout mono -i hw:1 -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 -f mpegts udp://44.0.0.95:1234
```

ffmpeg report/log:

```
ffmpeg started on 2015-06-15 at 19:14:26
Report written to "ffmpeg-20150615-191426.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -report -probesize 32000 -thread_queue_size 1024 -y -f h264 -r 25 -framerate 25 -i - -thread_queue_size 512 -f alsa -ac 1 -channel_layout mono -i hw:1 -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 -f mpegts udp://44.0.0.95:1234
ffmpeg version N-72834-gfd004e1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-probesize' ... matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '32000'.
Reading option '-thread_queue_size' ... matched as option 'thread_queue_size' (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument '1024'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'h264'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '25'.
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '25'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '-'.
Reading option '-thread_queue_size' ... matched as option 'thread_queue_size' (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument '512'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'alsa'.
Reading option '-ac' ... matched as option 'ac' (set number of audio channels) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-channel_layout' ... matched as option 'channel_layout' (set channel layout) with argument 'mono'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'hw:1'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'mp3'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mpegts'.
Reading option 'udp://44.0.0.95:1234' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file -.
Applying option thread_queue_size (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument 1024.
Applying option f (force format) with argument h264.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 25.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: -.
[h264 @ 0x12a83c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:4096 seeks:0
[h264 @ 0x12a83c0] Probe buffer size limit of 32000 bytes reached
[h264 @ 0x12a83c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[h264 @ 0x12a83c0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0x12a83c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 34816 bytes read:53248 seeks:0 frames:3
Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 3, 1/1200000: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input file hw:1.
Applying option thread_queue_size (set the maximum number of queued packets from the demuxer) with argument 512.
Applying option f (force format) with argument alsa.
Applying option ac (set number of audio channels) with argument 1.
Applying option channel_layout (set channel layout) with argument mono.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: hw:1.
[alsa @ 0x12cee80] All info found
Input #1, alsa, from 'hw:1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1434392072.070301, bitrate: 768 kb/s
    Stream #1:0, 1, 1/1000000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file udp://44.0.0.95:1234.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument mp3.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mpegts.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: udp://44.0.0.95:1234.
Matched encoder 'libmp3lame' for codec 'mp3'.
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x12a82a0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x12a82a0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x12a82a0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x12a82a0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x4'
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x12a82a0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x4
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x12a0390] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's32p|fltp|s16p'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x12a0390] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '44100|48000|32000|22050|24000|16000|11025|12000|8000'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x12a0390] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x4|0x3'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x12a0390] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'audio format for output stream 0:1'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1320b60] query_formats: 4 queried, 6 merged, 3 already done, 0 delayed
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x1321c60] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:48000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16p r:48000Hz
[mpegts @ 0x12bdbf0] muxrate VBR, pcr every 2 pkts, sdt every 200, pat/pmt every 40 pkts
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://44.0.0.95:1234':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/90000: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     276kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=5130.7kbits/s    
frame=   24 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=     494kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate=4212.8kbits/s    
frame=   36 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=     681kB time=00:00:01.44 bitrate=3872.8kbits/s    
frame=   49 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=     877kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=3664.8kbits/s    
frame=   62 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=    1119kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=3695.1kbits/s    
frame=   74 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=    1309kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=3622.3kbits/s    
frame=   87 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    1503kB time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=3539.2kbits/s    
frame=   99 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=    1677kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate=3470.2kbits/s    
frame=  112 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    1873kB time=00:00:04.48 bitrate=3424.6kbits/s    
frame=  125 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    2121kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=3475.1kbits/s    
frame=  137 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    2300kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=3437.8kbits/s    
frame=  150 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    2486kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=3394.5kbits/s    
frame=  162 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    2657kB time=00:00:06.48 bitrate=3358.5kbits/s    
frame=  175 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    2852kB time=00:00:07.00 bitrate=3337.4kbits/s    
frame=  188 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3124kB time=00:00:07.52 bitrate=3403.6kbits/s    
frame=  200 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3416kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=3497.7kbits/s    
frame=  213 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3679kB time=00:00:08.52 bitrate=3537.4kbits/s    
frame=  226 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    3976kB time=00:00:09.04 bitrate=3603.4kbits/s    
frame=  239 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    4228kB time=00:00:09.56 bitrate=3622.7kbits/s    
frame=  251 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    4502kB time=00:00:10.04 bitrate=3673.7kbits/s    
frame=  263 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    4761kB time=00:00:10.52 bitrate=3707.7kbits/s    
frame=  276 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    5135kB time=00:00:11.04 bitrate=3810.1kbits/s    
frame=  289 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    5458kB time=00:00:11.56 bitrate=3867.7kbits/s    
frame=  302 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    5831kB time=00:00:12.08 bitrate=3954.1kbits/s    
frame=  314 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    6107kB time=00:00:12.56 bitrate=3982.8kbits/s    
frame=  327 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    6364kB time=00:00:13.08 bitrate=3985.8kbits/s    
frame=  339 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    6674kB time=00:00:13.56 bitrate=4032.2kbits/s    
frame=  352 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    7217kB time=00:00:14.08 bitrate=4198.9kbits/s    
frame=  365 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    7714kB time=00:00:14.60 bitrate=4328.5kbits/s    
frame=  377 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    7969kB time=00:00:15.08 bitrate=4329.3kbits/s    
frame=  390 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    8194kB time=00:00:15.60 bitrate=4302.8kbits/s    
frame=  402 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    8397kB time=00:00:16.08 bitrate=4277.8kbits/s    
frame=  414 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    8597kB time=00:00:16.56 bitrate=4252.9kbits/s    
frame=  427 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    8874kB time=00:00:17.08 bitrate=4256.3kbits/s    
frame=  440 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    9092kB time=00:00:17.60 bitrate=4231.8kbits/s    
frame=  453 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    9321kB time=00:00:18.12 bitrate=4213.8kbits/s    
frame=  465 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    9512kB time=00:00:18.60 bitrate=4189.3kbits/s    
frame=  478 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    9721kB time=00:00:19.12 bitrate=4164.9kbits/s    
frame=  490 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=    9983kB time=00:00:19.60 bitrate=4172.7kbits/s    
frame=  503 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   10173kB time=00:00:20.12 bitrate=4142.1kbits/s    
frame=  515 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   10366kB time=00:00:20.60 bitrate=4122.1kbits/s    
frame=  528 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   10571kB time=00:00:21.12 bitrate=4100.4kbits/s    
frame=  540 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   10780kB time=00:00:21.60 bitrate=4088.2kbits/s    
frame=  553 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   11118kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate=4117.6kbits/s    
frame=  566 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   11360kB time=00:00:22.64 bitrate=4110.4kbits/s    
frame=  578 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   11584kB time=00:00:23.12 bitrate=4104.6kbits/s    
frame=  591 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   11852kB time=00:00:23.64 bitrate=4107.2kbits/s    
frame=  603 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   12123kB time=00:00:24.12 bitrate=4117.4kbits/s    
frame=  617 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   12346kB time=00:00:24.68 bitrate=4098.2kbits/s    
frame=  629 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   12543kB time=00:00:25.16 bitrate=4083.8kbits/s    
frame=  641 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   12781kB time=00:00:25.64 bitrate=4083.4kbits/s    
frame=  654 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   12996kB time=00:00:26.16 bitrate=4069.8kbits/s    
frame=  667 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   13313kB time=00:00:26.68 bitrate=4087.9kbits/s    
frame=  679 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   13539kB time=00:00:27.16 bitrate=4083.7kbits/s    
frame=  692 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   13774kB time=00:00:27.68 bitrate=4076.6kbits/s    
frame=  704 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   14011kB time=00:00:28.16 bitrate=4075.9kbits/s    
frame=  717 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   14210kB time=00:00:28.68 bitrate=4059.0kbits/s    
frame=  729 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   14462kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate=4063.0kbits/s    
frame=  742 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   14676kB time=00:00:29.68 bitrate=4050.9kbits/s    
frame=  755 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   14892kB time=00:00:30.20 bitrate=4039.5kbits/s    
frame=  767 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   15090kB time=00:00:30.68 bitrate=4029.1kbits/s    
frame=  780 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   15326kB time=00:00:31.20 bitrate=4024.2kbits/s    
frame=  792 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   15793kB time=00:00:31.68 bitrate=4083.9kbits/s    
frame=  805 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   16167kB time=00:00:32.20 bitrate=4112.9kbits/s    
frame=  818 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   16652kB time=00:00:32.72 bitrate=4169.0kbits/s    
frame=  830 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   16917kB time=00:00:33.20 bitrate=4174.3kbits/s    
frame=  843 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   17224kB time=00:00:33.72 bitrate=4184.4kbits/s    
frame=  855 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   17441kB time=00:00:34.20 bitrate=4177.6kbits/s    
frame=  868 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   17678kB time=00:00:34.72 bitrate=4171.0kbits/s    
frame=  881 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   17908kB time=00:00:35.24 bitrate=4163.1kbits/s    
frame=  893 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   18119kB time=00:00:35.72 bitrate=4155.5kbits/s    
frame=  906 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   18401kB time=00:00:36.24 bitrate=4159.6kbits/s    
frame=  918 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   18617kB time=00:00:36.72 bitrate=4153.3kbits/s    
frame=  931 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   18854kB time=00:00:37.24 bitrate=4147.5kbits/s    
frame=  944 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   19084kB time=00:00:37.76 bitrate=4140.3kbits/s    
frame=  956 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   19293kB time=00:00:38.24 bitrate=4133.0kbits/s    
frame=  969 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   19612kB time=00:00:38.76 bitrate=4145.0kbits/s    
frame=  981 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   19807kB time=00:00:39.24 bitrate=4135.0kbits/s    
frame=  994 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   20021kB time=00:00:39.76 bitrate=4125.1kbits/s    
frame= 1007 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   20233kB time=00:00:40.28 bitrate=4114.9kbits/s    
frame= 1020 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   20453kB time=00:00:40.80 bitrate=4106.5kbits/s    
frame= 1032 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   20704kB time=00:00:41.28 bitrate=4108.7kbits/s    
frame= 1045 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   20915kB time=00:00:41.80 bitrate=4099.0kbits/s    
frame= 1058 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   21168kB time=00:00:42.32 bitrate=4097.6kbits/s    
frame= 1070 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   21518kB time=00:00:42.80 bitrate=4118.6kbits/s    
frame= 1082 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   22021kB time=00:00:43.28 bitrate=4168.1kbits/s    
frame= 1095 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   22460kB time=00:00:43.80 bitrate=4200.8kbits/s    
frame= 1107 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   22899kB time=00:00:44.28 bitrate=4236.4kbits/s    
frame= 1120 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   23297kB time=00:00:44.80 bitrate=4260.1kbits/s    
frame= 1133 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   23649kB time=00:00:45.32 bitrate=4274.9kbits/s    
frame= 1145 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   23979kB time=00:00:45.80 bitrate=4289.0kbits/s    
frame= 1158 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   24220kB time=00:00:46.32 bitrate=4283.5kbits/s    
frame= 1170 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   24429kB time=00:00:46.80 bitrate=4276.1kbits/s    
frame= 1182 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   24666kB time=00:00:47.28 bitrate=4273.6kbits/s    
frame= 1196 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   24886kB time=00:00:47.84 bitrate=4261.5kbits/s    
frame= 1208 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   25133kB time=00:00:48.32 bitrate=4261.0kbits/s    
frame= 1221 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   25332kB time=00:00:48.84 bitrate=4249.0kbits/s    
frame= 1233 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   25525kB time=00:00:49.32 bitrate=4239.6kbits/s    
frame= 1246 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   25733kB time=00:00:49.84 bitrate=4229.7kbits/s    
frame= 1259 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   25941kB time=00:00:50.36 bitrate=4219.8kbits/s    
frame= 1271 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   26186kB time=00:00:50.84 bitrate=4219.5kbits/s    
frame= 1284 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   26387kB time=00:00:51.36 bitrate=4208.8kbits/s    
frame= 1296 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   26574kB time=00:00:51.84 bitrate=4199.3kbits/s    
frame= 1309 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   26780kB time=00:00:52.36 bitrate=4189.9kbits/s    
frame= 1322 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   27029kB time=00:00:52.88 bitrate=4187.3kbits/s    
frame= 1334 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   27223kB time=00:00:53.36 bitrate=4179.4kbits/s    
frame= 1347 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   27424kB time=00:00:53.88 bitrate=4169.7kbits/s    
frame= 1359 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   27610kB time=00:00:54.36 bitrate=4160.7kbits/s    
frame= 1372 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   27813kB time=00:00:54.88 bitrate=4151.6kbits/s    
frame= 1385 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   28062kB time=00:00:55.40 bitrate=4149.6kbits/s    
frame= 1397 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   28246kB time=00:00:55.88 bitrate=4140.8kbits/s    
frame= 1410 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   28449kB time=00:00:56.40 bitrate=4132.1kbits/s    
frame= 1422 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   28631kB time=00:00:56.88 bitrate=4123.5kbits/s    
frame= 1435 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   28837kB time=00:00:57.40 bitrate=4115.5kbits/s    
frame= 1448 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   29086kB time=00:00:57.92 bitrate=4113.8kbits/s    
frame= 1460 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   29269kB time=00:00:58.40 bitrate=4105.7kbits/s    
frame= 1473 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   29465kB time=00:00:58.92 bitrate=4096.7kbits/s    
frame= 1485 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   29646kB time=00:00:59.40 bitrate=4088.5kbits/s    
frame= 1498 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   29845kB time=00:00:59.92 bitrate=4080.3kbits/s    
frame= 1511 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   30097kB time=00:01:00.44 bitrate=4079.3kbits/s    
frame= 1523 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   30281kB time=00:01:00.92 bitrate=4072.0kbits/s    
frame= 1536 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   30474kB time=00:01:01.44 bitrate=4063.2kbits/s    
frame= 1548 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   30653kB time=00:01:01.92 bitrate=4055.4kbits/s    
frame= 1561 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   30853kB time=00:01:02.44 bitrate=4047.8kbits/s    
frame= 1574 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   31100kB time=00:01:02.96 bitrate=4046.5kbits/s    
frame= 1586 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   31291kB time=00:01:03.44 bitrate=4040.6kbits/s    
frame= 1599 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   31499kB time=00:01:03.96 bitrate=4034.3kbits/s    
frame= 1611 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   31686kB time=00:01:04.44 bitrate=4028.1kbits/s    
frame= 1624 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   31940kB time=00:01:04.96 bitrate=4027.9kbits/s    
frame= 1637 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   32135kB time=00:01:05.48 bitrate=4020.4kbits/s    
frame= 1649 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   32320kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate=4014.0kbits/s    
frame= 1661 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   32496kB time=00:01:06.44 bitrate=4006.7kbits/s    
frame= 1674 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   32685kB time=00:01:06.96 bitrate=3998.7kbits/s    
frame= 1687 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   32932kB time=00:01:07.48 bitrate=3997.9kbits/s    
frame= 1699 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   33175kB time=00:01:07.96 bitrate=3999.0kbits/s    
frame= 1712 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   33507kB time=00:01:08.48 bitrate=4008.3kbits/s    
frame= 1724 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   33797kB time=00:01:08.96 bitrate=4014.9kbits/s    
frame= 1737 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   34091kB time=00:01:09.48 bitrate=4019.5kbits/s    
frame= 1750 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   34451kB time=00:01:10.00 bitrate=4031.8kbits/s    
frame= 1763 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   34750kB time=00:01:10.52 bitrate=4036.7kbits/s    
frame= 1775 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size=   35010kB time=00:01:11.00 bitrate=4039.5kbits/s    
[libmp3lame @ 0x1320770] Trying to remove 47 more samples than there are in the queue
frame= 1779 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=   35116kB time=00:01:11.28 bitrate=4035.7kbits/s    
video:31803kB audio:557kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.515517%
Input file #0 (pipe:):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 1779 packets read (32566370 bytes); 
  Total: 1779 packets (32566370 bytes) demuxed
Input file #1 (hw:1):
  Input stream #1:0 (audio): 57720 packets read (6842992 bytes); 57720 frames decoded (3421496 samples); 
  Total: 57720 packets (6842992 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (udp://44.0.0.95:1234):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1779 packets muxed (32566370 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 2970 frames encoded (3421440 samples); 2971 packets muxed (570432 bytes); 
  Total: 4750 packets (33136802 bytes) muxed
57720 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x1321210] Statistics: 0 seeks, 25491 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x12a7e40] Statistics: 35211617 bytes read, 0 seeks
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Comment: Are you running your Pi headless or do you have a monitor attached? I ask because I've found that H264 video from webcams has a tendency to lag by a couple of seconds when viewing in real time (i.e., lip sync's off when one's speaking into the camera), and you'd need a monitor to verify whether or not this is the source of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what tool I would use to test this. How would I know that the problem was not with the tool?

Comment: If your Pi has a monitor, using the `raspivid` preview function (e.g., `raspivid -t 0 -p '0,0,1280,720'`) should allow you to check output sync in real time. If you're speaking into the camera, for instance, you'll immediately know if the camera's lagging behind. If you're running headless, trying to diagnose sync problems by way of a viewable stream isn't going to help much. You can, however, attempt to delay the audio by using an `-itsoffset` option. Details coming shortly in a proposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd suggest: If you're able to test the output sync of your camera by using a `raspvid` preview window and you find the camera to be lagging behind, then I'd say the camera's h264 encoder is to blame. If it's in sync, however, then FFmpeg is doing a number on the piped input.

**If the camera's h264 encoder is the problem** and the video lag behind the audio is of a consistent duration (i.e., you observe a 2.5-second lag every time), you can add an `-itsoffset` parameter to the audio input to delay it by that duration. E.g:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 | \
ffmpeg -report -y \
-f h264 -r 25 -i - \
-itsoffset 2.5 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 \
-vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
-f mpegts udp://44.0.0.95:1234
```

**If there's no lag in the camera's preview output**, then I'd suggest installing the camera's V4L2 driver so your FFmpeg command can pull frames from the camera directly.

```
ffmpeg -report -y \
-f v4l2 -input_format h264 -r 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 \
-f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 \
-vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
-f mpegts udp://44.0.0.95:1234
```

However, from what I've gathered online, folks have complaints about the performance of the V4L2 driver of this camera, so you might end up sticking with the devil you know and using `-itsoffset` on the audio input regardless.

Command Notes: I've trimmed off the `probesize` option from your command since you're specifying the input format and framerate. Also, you shouldn't specify both `-r 25` (which 'forces' the framerate to specified value) *and* `-framerate 25` (which would attempt to use the 'native' input framerate). I've left `-r 25` in because I've found that it works better for live video inputs. The MP3 encoder settings are more specific just so FFmpeg doesn't have to "guess" about them. `-thread_queue_size` params were trimmed off for line-length, so you can add them back in if absolutely necessary.

Comment: The issue was probesize for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to restream audio on rtp://127.0.0.1:1235 and combine the video in mp4 container.

Comment: How do you do this? What will it achieve? How does it solve the askers issue? As it stands this could be useful but it is very low quality.